# React Native change status bar color

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having some trouble with changing my status bar color in my RN App, on IOS.
What I am doing is i'm following the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar) and just doing a

```
<ScreenWrapper flex={1}>
  <StatusBar backgroundColor="#1d78ef" barStyle="light-content" />
  <ScrollView>
    ...content
  </ScrollView>
</ScreenWrapper>
```

However, it does not work on IOS, as the docs say. Are there any known workarounds?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/status-bar/

Comment: **backgroundColor** is android only prop, It won't work on iOS. You can use **SafeAreaView** with `flex: 0, backgroundColor: '#1d78ef'` for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I created a component for this. You can use different codes for Android and iOS like below. I am using `SafeAreaView` but you can use just `View` if you want.

```
class SafeAreaWithStatusBarView extends Component {
renderAndroid() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor }}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor={this.props.statusBarColor} barStyle={this.props.barStyle} />
        {this.props.children}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  renderIOS() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: this.props.statusBarColor }} />
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor }}>
          <StatusBar barStyle={this.props.barStyle} />
          {this.props.children}
        </SafeAreaView>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return Platform.OS === 'ios' ? this.renderIOS() : this.renderAndroid();
  }
}
```